# Is there a method for computing logarithms similar to Square and Multiply for exponentiation?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, exponentiation

I used the Square and Multiply method and now I was wondering if there is a similar thing for the computation of logarithms. Shouldn't it be exactly the opposite of Square and Multiply? And if so where do you start?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "square and multiply"?  If you are simply saying, for example, calculating $a^9$ by squaring a to get $a^2$, squaring again to get $a^4$, squaring again to get $a^8$, then finally multiplying by a to get $a^9$, that is $not$ a general method for finding powers.  You cannot, for example, use that to find $a^\pi$.

Comment: I'm referring to this method [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) so it can only be used for positive integer powers of a number. And I'd like to know if there is a similar thing for logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar technique to compute the integer part of $\log_b x$: Repeatedly square $b$ until you get something larger than $x$, then divide out the repeated squares starting with the largest one, unless that would get you below $1$.

One difference from exponentiation-by-squaring is that you need to *store* all the repeated squares because you need to use them in the opposite order they were produced in.

Instead of dividing (which is often expensive) you can start an accumulator at $1$ and keep *multiplying* in the repeated squares, discarding the product if it exceeds $x$.

In order to get at the *fractional* part of $\log_b x$ you can continue by taking repeated *square roots* of $b$, which is expensive. But if all your logs are to the same base (or you compute $\log_b x$ as $\frac{\log x}{\log b}$ for a common base), you can once and for all compute a *table* of repeated square roots of the base and use that for all of your logarithm calculations. A variation of this can yield a CORDIC-like algorithm for logarithms.

All this only works for numbers that you can *compare*. Logarithms groups or ring that doesn't have a well-behaved order is thought to be a hard problem. (And the hardness of this problem in particular settings is the basis of several cryptographic primitives).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a nice Sunday:)